# Behavior of Generics in the TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to study TS a bit, and I am following the official [page](http://www.typescriptlang.org).

I am on the [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) chapter

From the guide:

```
function identity(arg: any): any {
    return arg;
}
```

They state the following:

> While using any is certainly generic in that it will cause the function to accept any and all types for the type of arg, we actually are **losing the information** about what that type was when the function returns. If we passed in a number, the only information we have is that any type could be returned.

Now lets observe this piece of code:

```
let whatIsMyType = identity(666);
typeof whatIsMyType; // number
```

I have not lost type information. What kind of loss they refer to?

Reading a bit further, guide suggests to use T type, as in:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

With explanation:

> We’ve now added a type variable T to the identity function. This T
>   allows us to capture the type the user provides (e.g. number), so that
>   we can use that information later. Here, we use T again as the return
>   type. On inspection, we can now see the same type is used for the
>   argument and the return type. This allows us to traffic that type
>   information in one side of the function and out the other.

And lastly:
function in TS (with any type of signature)

```
function identity(arg: any): any {
    return arg;
}
```

and the function with generic type T:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
return arg;
```

}

once compiled to plain JS, they look both identical:

```
function identity(arg) {
    return arg;
}
```

Now, I understand the benefit of early warning, I also understand the **any** signature. What I do not understand why saying I lost the type, and I should use **"T"** signature instead.

Which is more complicated, and is basically identical.

Comment: Excellent question. This is a point of confusion for a lot of people learning typescript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now lets observe this piece of code:
> let whatIsMyType = identity(666);
> typeof whatIsMyType; // number
> I have not lost type information. What kind of loss they refer to?

It's about the difference between static type information and runtime type information. TypeScript is all about static type information — the information available to the TypeScript compiler to help you keep your program code correct. But `typeof` (in that context¹) is a [*JavaScript* runtime operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) telling you (in very general terms) what kind of value is stored in the variable `whatIsMyType` at runtime as of when you use `typeof` on it.

If you paste that code into [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAFAQwCcBzALkXzGwEpzLtEBvAKETcULShEKSOIDczAL7MANl0QB3ABb4oASQDOAWWwAVbAAc0iALzJ0mGDlwA2C9SEQESuBIB0YuMVyz5ytZp1Xm7xaoa2roGAETAcHCh1rb2aE4ubnIBXsFWQA) and hover your mouse over the `whatIsMyType` variable, you'll see that it's TypeScript type is `any`, which means you can happily assign `"foo"` (or anything else) to it after the call to `identity`:

```
function identity(arg: any): any {
    return arg;
}
let whatIsMyType = identity(666);
console.log(whatIsMyType);
whatIsMyType = "foo";          // No error here
console.log(whatIsMyType);
```

Because its type is `any`, the variable is loosely typed like JavaScript variables are.

TypeScript's goal, its raison d'être, is static (compile-time) type checking. The `any` type is an escape hatch for those situations where static type checking isn't useful (or even possible because of third-party integrations). (And those situations do exist, but are rare.)

> once compiled to plain JS, they look both identical:

That's right. The static type information that TypeScript uses is not part of the final output. It's a compile-time thing, not a runtime thing. (Enums have a small runtime presence.) But notice how, at compile-time, using the generic changes things — if you run this code [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFQD4AKAQwCcBzALkXwEpb9EBvAKEU8XLShHKQVKAbjYBfNgBteiAO4ALUlACSAZwCy2fNgAOaRAF5k6TDBzEAbFfqiICVXGkA6SXErEFStZu16bbTxUNLV19IwAiYDg4cNt7RzQXNw9FIJ9QmyA):

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
let whatIsMyType = identity(666);
console.log(whatIsMyType);
whatIsMyType = "foo";       // <== Error: Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type 'number'.
console.log(whatIsMyType);
```

...you can see that assigning `"foo"` to `whatIsMyType` is now a compile-time error.

---

¹ *"..`typeof` (in that context)..."* Somewhat confusingly, there is also a [TypeScript `typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#handbook-content) that you can use in a *type* context, which is different from JavaScript's runtime `typeof` keyword (used in your example) which is used in a *value* context. In TypeScript, there are places a *type* is expected (a *type context*), such as after the `:` in a variable declaration:

```
let a: type_expected_here;
```

...and other places a *value* is expected (a *value context*), such as the right-hand side of an assignment:

```
a = value_expected_here;
```

If you use `typeof` in a *type context*, it's TypeScript's `typeof` operator. For instance, if you have this declaration:

```
let foo: number = 42;
```

...you can use `typeof bar` to declare a variable whose type is the same as `foo`'s, [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jBcEB2BXAtgIxAJwNwCh9RIBDRMATwAcQYpo5cIB6ZiAAxPYHIBnCSjQgBLfu1SYc7IA):

```
let a: typeof foo;
```

Since that usage of `typeof` is where a *type* is expected, `a` will have the type `number` because that's `foo`'s type. If you change `foo`'s declaration so it's a string instead, `a`'s type will change to follow suit.

In contrast:

```
let a = typeof foo;
```

There, `typeof` is in a *value context*, so it's JavaScript's runtime `typeof` keyword, and `a` will get the value (not type) `"number"` (an in that specific example, `a`'s type will be inferred as `string`, since that's what JavaScript's `typeof`'s result always is).

That seems very confusing at first, but gets clearer with time.

---

Note that all of the above is from a TypeScript perspective. Whether you find static type checking a help or a hindrance is up to you. :-) But I'm assuming a TypeScript perspective for the purposes of this answer.